# Micro apps for mobile

Tags: mobile

Could someone guide me how to make a mobile application (that can be executed in web, android and ios) that is a container of micro applications? , that is, I need to make an application for mobile (Android and IOS) that uses other independent applications that perform a specific task. On the internet I found an example of micro applications for web but not for mobiles.

If you could indicate which frameworks to use and if there are any examples.

In advance thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

i think Java script "Node.JS framework" work on mobiles and web if that what do you mean